# laravel datatable show data if Eloquent columns empty

Tags: laravel, datatable

Im using datatables for displaying data from 3 tables, the problem is if vendor_id in check table is empty,will not display the row and so on
So I want to display all data even if the columns that are in relationship with other tables empty

Controller

```php
 $vendorTableName= with(new Vendors())->getTable();
 $categoryTableName= with(new Excategories())->getTable();
 $orders =Checks::select(["checks.*","vendors.vendor_name","excategories.category_name"])->between($start, $end)->join($vendorTableName,$vendorTableName.".vendor_id","=","checks.vendor_id")->join($categoryTableName,$categoryTableName.".category_id","=","checks.category_id");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `join()` method which translates into SQL **inner join**
if you want to get data even if the other tables are empty you must use the `leftJoin` method instead.

Also i would suggest you to take a look at the official documenation for joins:
[docs for eloquent joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins)

and there is a popular StakOverflow question about the differences in joins:
[understanding the difference between different joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)